# Selenium framework for two different systems integrating with eachother

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver with Testng framework.  I have three different systems where the output of first system is the input to the second and output of second system is input to the third one.

first system has its own UI which can be only executed in Chrome and second and third has UI which can executed only in IE. Calls beteween systems are Asynchronous. Can some one help how to design this?

Comment: What is your outputs? What exactly do you mean by "calls beteween systems are Asynchronous"?

Comment: For eg  in first system we can add to shopping cart and that shopping cart will be sent to system 2 where order will be created and after that will be sent to third system where order will be confirmed

Comment: the calls between systems are XML calls

Answer (score 1):

You will create 3 driver for each browser. You will keep your outputs as variable and passing to other system call.

Answer (score 1):

You can create as many number of driver in a single script

Refer the below code. It's a just a example what you needed :-

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./src\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
    String output1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']")).getText();

    WebDriver driverIE=new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driverIE.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
    WebElement aa= driverIE.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']");
    aa.sendKeys(output1);

    WebDriver driverMFF= new FirefoxDriver();
    driverMFF.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
    String output3=driverMFF.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']")).getText();
```

In above demo script, I save the output of chromedriver and pass it to IE

Hope it will help :)